# Java Generics WildCard: <? extends Number> vs <T extends Number>

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between these 2 functions?

```
static void gPrint(List<? extends Number> l) {
    for (Number n : l) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}

static <T extends Number> void gPrintA(List<T> l) {
    for (Number n : l) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

I see the same output.

Comment: Perhaps that's because there's no difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/java-generics-e-and-t-what-is-the-difference

Comment: why we cant define class Name<? extends Number> but class Name<T extends Number> is fine ?

Comment: @PrateekJoshi Yes, I was thinking the same. Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is no difference in this case, because `T` is never used again.

The reason for declaring a `T` is so that you can refer to it again, thus binding two parameter types, or a return type together.

Comment: Agreed! So is there a case where only '?' will do the job for me but not 'T'. Or whatever that can be done by wildcard can be done using 'T'?

Comment: If there is only one `?`, then it is equivalent. If there is more than one `?`, then you have to use either `T` or `?`, depending on if you need the two types to be the same, or want to allow for them to be different. If you have a method `x(<? extends Number> a, <? extends Number> b)`, you can call it with an Integer and a Long. If you have `T a, T b`, they both need to be of the same type.

Comment: But I can still do <T extends Number, U extends Number> x(T a, U b). So which is the preferred way? Is it preferred to not use Wildcards (whenever possible)?

Comment: It is just a matter of style. I'd prefer wildcards, to make it clear that the type is not bound to another type.

Answer (score 49):

The difference is you can't refer to `T` when using a wildcard.

You aren't right now, so there is "no difference", but here's how you could use `T` to make a difference:

```
static <T extends Number> T getElement(List<T> l) {
    for (T t : l) {
        if (some condition)
            return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will return *the same type* as whatever is passed in. eg these will both compile:

```
Integer x = getElement(integerList);
Float y = getElement(floatList);
```

Comment: So when is wildcard really needed?

Comment: The wildcard is not really "needed", but provides for less typing when indeed it is an unbound type (no need to give it a name). The resulting code is equivalent. This is similar to the difference between `int a = 1; return a` versus `return 1`. Or writing `<T extends Object>` instead of `<T>`

Comment: @Bohemian Wait a second, how is that code correct? Isn't there type erasure that occurs at runtime, leading that code to fail out at runtime?

Comment: @Dr.Java Yes and no. Yes there’s runtime type erasure, but there’s no error at runtime because at compile time the type was *inferred* and type safety was assured. See [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Answer (score 15):

`T` is a bounded type, i.e. whatever type you use, you have to stick to that particular type which extends `Number`, e.g. if you pass a `Double` type to a list, you cannot pass it a `Short` type as `T` is of type `Double` and the list is already bounded by that type. In contrast, if you use `?` (`wildcard`), you can use "any" type that extends `Number` (add both `Short` and `Double` to that list).

Answer (score 0):

Why we use the upper bound wildcard is very well described in the [Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) section of Java Generics Tutorial.

As you already know; Integer, Long, Double and as well as a few other classes extend from the Number class. In other words all of them are subtypes of Number. Therefore, you can say "Integer is a Number", "Double is a Number" and so on.
However, the same relationship does NOT exist for List<Number> against List<Integer>, List<Double> and so on. In other words, List<Number> is not a base type of List<Integer>, List<Double> etc.

So, let's say, you want to write methods that must be able to work with all List of those types. In other words, your method should have a list argument, that could be a List<Integer>, List<Double>, List<Number> etc. In this case, you have to **use the upper bounded wildcard**.

In conclusion, List<? extends Number> is the base type of List<Integer>, List<Double>, List<Number> and etc.

Consider the following example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WildCardDemo {

  public static double sum1 (List<Number> list) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list) {
      result += n.doubleValue();
    }
    return result;
  }
/*
  public static <T> double sum2 (List<T extends Number> list) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list) {
      result += n.doubleValue();
    }
    return result;
  }
*/

  public static double sum3 (List<? extends Number> list) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list) {
      result += n.doubleValue();
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Double> numList = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);

    //System.out.println(sum1(numList));  // Compiler Error !!! incompatible types: List<Double> cannot be converted to List<Number>

    //System.out.println(sum2(numList)); // Compiler error !!!  sytax error

    System.out.println(sum3(numList)); // This works
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you use T you can perform all type of actions on List. But when you use  you can not perform add.

T -  as same as object reference with full access 
? -  give partial access

```
static void gPrint(List<? extends Number> l) {
 l.add(1); //Will give error
for (Number n : l) {
    System.out.println(n);
}

static <T extends Number> void gPrintA(List<T> l) {
l.add((T)1); //We can add
for (Number n : l) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```