# Understanding Java Generics <T extends Class> and <? extends Class>

Tags: java, generics

This may be a dumb question so please excuse my ignorance.

Lets say I have a class:

```
public class Foo<T extends Base> implements Bar<T> {
    private Bar<T> wrapped;
    public void setWrapped(Bar<T> input) {
        wrapped = input;
    }
}
```

If I call it with:

```
//Lets just assume methods getNewVal and getFoo exist
Bar<? extends Base> val = getNewVal();
Foo<? extends Base> foo = getFoo();
foo.setWrapped(val);
```

The compiler says **foo.execute(val)** is an error. With a message along the lines of **The method setWrapped(Bar<capture#20-of ? extends Base>) in the type Foo<capture#20-of ? extends Base> is not applicable for the arguments (Bar<capture#22-of ? extends Base>)**.

If I try to change Foo to be

```
public class Foo<T extends Base> implements Bar<T> {
    private Bar<T> wrapped;
    public void setWrapped(Bar<? extends Base> input) {
        wrapped = input;
    }
}
```

The call to **foo.setWrapped(val)** no longer errors. Instead **wrapped = input** is an error with a message along the lines of **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Bar<capture#1-of ? extends Base> to Bar<T>**.

What am I doing wrong? Is there not a way to get the compiler to be okay with a call like this without casting?

Comment: That is because `?` is not the same as `?`. The compiler cannot verify that the `?` in `Bar<? extends Base>` is the *same* `?` as in `Foo<? extends Base>`, so they are not compatible.

Comment: There's almost no way to use a wildcard as a return type, which is what you're doing in the second code example.  C.f. PECS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super  Those wildcards are for making generics easier to use with method parameters, not return types.

Comment: Example: `getNewVal()` returns `Bar<HomeBase>`, and `getFoo()` returns `Foo<ThirdBase>`. That is perfectly valid for first two statements, but not for `setWrapped()`.

Comment: Could we get some more concrete code?

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I understand why it doesn't work that way now. Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497020/java-generics-wildcard-extends-number-vs-t-extends-number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Generics WildCard: <? extends Number> vs <T extends Number>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497020/java-generics-wildcard-extends-number-vs-t-extends-number)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you *want* is

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar<? extends Base> wrapped;
    public void setWrapped(Bar<? extends Base> input) {
        wrapped = input;
    }
}
```

It's not clear what the `Bar` interface `Foo` needs to implement is, though, and why `Foo` should have a `Bar` as well as *be* a `Bar`.