# Java Collection methods

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn Java and I have a question about generics.

In this methods from `Collection<E>` interface:

`boolean containsAll( Collection <?> c);

boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c);

boolean retainAll ( Collection <?> c);`

Why is the parameter  `Collection <?> c` instead of `Collection <E> c`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: well you should first ask something "simpler": why `contains(Object)` not `contains(E)`.

Comment: smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Comment: @LouisWasserman @irreputable Ok, thanks for the link. I have understood that.  But then, why is the parameter in containsAll `<?>` and not `<? extends Object>`? Maybe because it's redundant, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics ? , E and T what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/java-generics-e-and-t-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDK designers wanted code like the following to be possible:

```
Collection<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
Collection<Object> objects = Arrays.asList("foo", 123);
strings.removeAll(objects);
// strigns now contains only "bar" and "baz"
```

(The above code might not exactly compile because I can't remember how `Arrays.asList()` captures type parameters, but it should get the point across.)

That is, because you can call `.equals()` on any pair of objects and get a meaningful result, you don't really need to restrict those methods to a specific item type.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `E` type parameter needs to be specified while a wildcard `?` works for every type. The subtle difference is that

- `E` means any specified type
- `?` means any unknown type

Since there methods are supposed to work on a collection of any unknown type then they doesn't specify a type parameter at all. `E` is a type variable. `?` is not a variable, is a placeholder which cannot be specified.

Comment: Those methods appear to be taken from `Collection<E>`, so they do have the type parameter in scope.