# Clarification about wildcards (Generics) in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have recently started reading Core Java. But I am having a hard time grasping the concept of wildcards.

Specifically, I'm confused about the difference between the following:

```
public class A<T extends {some_class}> {/*...*/}
```

and

```
public class A<? extends {some_class}> {/*...*/}
```

Can anyone help me understand the difference if there is at all?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/java-generics-e-and-t-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html  and   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html, you won't find better explanations.

Comment: The difference is that the second one is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you cannot use the `?` elsewhere while you can use `T`.  For example:

```
public class Foo<T extends Number> {
  T value; // you can declare fields of type T here

  int foo() {
    // Since you said T extends Number, you can call methods of Number on value
    return value.intValue(); 
  }
}
```

So why would you use `?` at all?  If you don't need the type.  It wouldn't make sense to use it in a class definition any way that I can think of.  But you could use it in a method like this:

```
int getListSize(List<?> list) {
    return list.size();
}
```

Any kind of method where you're more interested in the overall class and it has a method that doesn't involve the paramaterized type would work here.  `Class.getName()` is another example.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, except with the wildcard you can't refer to the type in the code of your class. Using `T` names the type.

Comment: If in case of wildcard, one can't refer to the type, then why would one use it? It's confusing me a lot.

Comment: I can't think if a reason. Java has some whacky syntax that while it compiles, it doesn't make sense. Where you use wildcards is in typing variables, where you don't care or need to know the *actual* type, only its abstract (bounded) type.

Answer (score 0):

In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.

The Type T is a defined type or known type

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
? extends some class   or T extends some_class
```

means   `some_class` itself or any of its children  and anything that would work with instanceof some_class.

As per conventions T is meant to be a Type   and `?` is unknown type.