# Generics with autoboxing and unboxing of primitives

Tags: java, generics, primitive-types, autoboxing, unboxing

Why autoboxing and unboxing of primitives not happens with Generics Java.

```
public static <T extends Number> T addNumber(T a , T b)
{
  int c = a*b;
  System.out.println(c);
  return c; 
}
```

Here why * operation can't be performed and why can't return c.Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int c = a*b;
```

This statement actually works, since `T` is bounded by `Integer`, so after erasure, the types of `a` and `b` are `Integer` and they are unboxed to int.

```
return c;
```

This doesn't work since the return type of the method is not `Integer`, it is `T`, and even though `<T extends Integer>` and `Integer` is `final`, so `T` can only be `Integer`, the compiler doesn't allow that, since it doesn't take the `finality` of the type bound into account (i.e. as far as it's concerned, the method can accept instances of a sub-class of the type bound, and it can't auto-box `int` to any sub-class of the type bound).

Changing the return type to `Integer` will make the code pass compilation :

```
public static <T extends Integer> Integer addNumber(T a , T b){
  int c = a*b;
  System.out.println(c);
  return c;
}
```

Of course, it doesn't make sense to use `Integer` (or any final class) as a type bound for a generic type parameter.

Comment: if <T extends Number> it is not allowing a *b

Comment: @Pooja But your type bound is `Integer` not `Number`. If you change the type bound to `Number`, `int c = a.intValue ()*b.intValue ();` will work instead. `Number` cannot be unboxed automatically to an int.

Comment: Thanks. I was considering Number to be autoboxed automatically.

Comment: But if I extend it with Integer so why it can not return int  even If Integer class can not be subclassed.

Comment: @Pooja `int` can only be boxed to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are not supposed to be used with primitive types. T indicates a type parameter which should be an object. 
More reference
[Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)
[Java Generics ? , E and T what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/java-generics-e-and-t-what-is-the-difference)
[Restrictions on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)

Comment: Integer is also a wrapper class and if we do mathematics operation on its object it is allowed , So why not if T extends Integer