# What is the difference between empty generics<> and <E>,<T> notation in java?

Tags: java, generics

I know E and T can be used interchangeably in Java generics. I also looked up this [Java Generics ? , E and T what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/java-generics-e-and-t-what-is-the-difference) answer , but couldn't find much information on empty generics and how is it different ?
Thanks

EDIT: I don't agree with the duplicate. The question link provided doesn't answer my question i.e the difference between <> and < E > or < T >

Comment: You mean [diamond operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Like "<>" ? Or the wildcards?

Comment: Yes , sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: Aren't `E` and `T` just names?

Comment: Actually, T and E are the most used letters but you can use what you want, even complete words, in order to enhance readability.

Comment: `T`, `E` (or any other word you wish to put) can be referenced later on on your code, `?` cannot.

Comment: So , can we replace '<>' with (<E> or <T>) and vice versa ?

Comment: @plutonium No, they are different things. (<E> or <T>) is a generic type. <> is only used when instantiating a class and only when Java can infer the type it should go there. So, it's not really a type, it's just a tool so you don't have to write the type if it's obvious. <?> is like (<E> or <T>) except that every time you write <?> in your code, it will be a different type. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan Thanks for the answer , BTW can we use <E> or <T> when instantiating a class instead of <> ?

Comment: @plutonium Yes, you can. In fact, there was no <> until Java 7.