# What does "T" stand for in Result<T, E> in Rust?

Tags: rust, acronym, rust-result

The official [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) makes a lot of references to `T`:

```rust
enum Result<T, E> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(E),
}
```

I gather that these are placeholder acronyms. While `E` should stand for "error", I'm not sure what `T` stands for.

Comment: Idk about in Rust, but often `T` is short for "type". It's just a generic name for a generic type, when the type doesn't have a more specific meaning.

Comment: It's not specific to Rust: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/what-is-the-difference-between-e-t-and-for-java-generics, for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a naming convention for a generic **t**ype.

Generic types in Rust are typically named with a single capital letter. The `non_camel_case_types` warning enforces that the name starts with a capital letter, but it's just a warning and nothing prevents you to name it otherwise.

`T` is the most commonly seen letter, you'll often see this where the item really doesn't care what the type represents, but there are some other letters commonly used in particular cases as follow:

- If the type is an error type: `E`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.err)

  ```rust
  fn err(self) -> Option<E>
  ```
- If the type is a predicate: `P`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter)

  ```rust
  fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P>
  where
      P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
  ```
- If the type is a function type: `F`, `G`, etc. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each)

  ```rust
  std::iter::Iterator::for_each<F>(self, f: F)
  where
      F: FnMut(Self::Item)
  ```
- If the type is the return type of a generic function: `R`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html#method.with)

  ```rust
  fn with<F, R>(&'static self, f: F) -> R
  where
      F: FnOnce(&T) -> R,
  ```
- If the type is a key type in some map: `K`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.keys)

  ```rust
  fn keys(&self) -> Keys<K, V>
  ```
- If the type is a value type in some map: `V`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.insert)

  ```rust
  fn insert(&mut self, key: K, value: V) -> Option<V>
  ```
- If the type is an implementation of [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html): `I`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Fuse.html)

  ```rust
  impl<I> Clone for Fuse<I> where
      I: Clone,
  ```
- If the type is an implementation of [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html): `R`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.chain)

  ```rust
  fn chain<R: Read>(self, next: R) -> Chain<Self, R>
  where
      Self: Sized,
  ```
- If the type is an implementation of [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html): `W`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html)

  ```rust
  struct BufWriter<W: Write> { /* fields omitted */ }
  ```
- If the type is an implementation of [`ToSocketAddrs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html): `A`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.connect)

  ```rust
  fn connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> Result<TcpStream>
  ```
- If the type is a path (ie. implements [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html)`<`[`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html)`>`): `P`. [Example:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open)

  ```rust
  pub fn open<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<File>
  ```
- Everything else: `T`, `U`, etc., usually in alphabetical order.

Comment: There's also `Fut` for futures, e.g. [lots in `futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/index.html).