# Rust understanding the letters U meaning in function declarations such a F, T, N etc

Tags: arrays, rust, types

I am trying to understand the source code of the array::map function. The docs show this as the signature

```
pub fn map<F, U>(self, f: F) -> [U; N]
where
    F: FnMut(T) -> U,
```

i know F represents function, the N is kind of like a fixed length. What does the U stand for? It takes a function/closure that returns a  U ? does it mean unsigned array?

Comment: https://learning-rust.github.io/docs/b4.generics.html

Comment: See also [“What does `T` stand for in `Result<T, E>` in Rust?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590029/what-does-t-stand-for-in-resultt-e-in-rust/60590428)

Comment: `U` is the return value of the function passed to `array::map`. `array::map` converts array of `T` to array of `U` by applying the given function to every element of the array, and creating a new array out of results. If you have an array of gadgets, you can use `.map()` to convert it to an array of widgets simply by calling `map()` with a function that takes a gadget and returns a widget.

Comment: As for why it was chosen - I guess that `T` usually stands for arbitrary `T`ype, and `U` is just the next letter in the alphabet, so it is used as the _second_ type.

Answer (score 1):

`U` can be any type. `U` is an unrestricted generic type parameter.

If you write a function `foo` like this and pass it to `map` (`map(foo)`) then rust will figure out that `U` is `bool` here. Because the parameter `F` is of the type `fn(u64) -> bool` (I assumed here that T is u64 as an example)

```rust
fn foo(_arg: u64) -> bool {
  ...
}
```

If you wrote a function `bar` like this and pass it to `map` (`map(bar)`) then rust will figure out that `U` is `String` here. Because the parameter `F` is of the type `fn(u64) -> String`

```rust
fn bar(_arg: u64) -> String {
  ...
}
```